# a failed upgrade of v17. 10 from a few days ago left OS crippled

Tags: dpkg

A recent upgrade of version 17.10 left my OS crippled. the system still boots up into a desktop, but it no longer connects to the network. it also no longer recognizes my monitor and runs in a vga or low resolution mode. There is a message about BrokenCount > 0 I tried running apt-get install --fix-broken and I get a dpkg error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-4.13.0.17-generic_4.13.0-17.20_amd64.deb (--unpack).  Can you suggest what I need to look at to solve this problem.

Comment: No longer connects to the network could be a kernel issue `dpkg error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-extra-4.13.0.17-generic_4.13.0-17.20_amd64.deb (--unpack)`, but there are so many things wrong that you should give up and reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Is your disk full? Do a `df -h` on the command line to see.

Comment: Oh, very sad. Thanks to both of you. There is plenty of disk space in all partitions. I was afraid that reinstall would end up as the path to take. I will wait a couple of days and hope that somebody may suggest an easy, magic fix, or a way to revert to a previous version and double check that my backups are in order.